# What should I do when sys.stdout.encoding is None?

Tags: python, character-encoding

I am trying to handle the different encodings in a Python script the more user-friendly and auto-magic way possible (there are APIs for utf8). It is a cross-platform console script.

For printing to `stdout` I use `sys.stdout.encoding` and it seems to do the right thing almost always when printing to the console. However when stdout is **piped** it becomes `None`.

So in that case I assume I am piping to a file and use `locale.getpreferredencoding()` but:

- I am not sure this is the right encoding for printing to a file, but it works quite cross-platform.
- That doesn't work when *piping to a program* `|`. I don't know how to detect that this is the case neither if there is **a standard or an expected behavior** for encoding in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is None, simply output your data as `utf-8`, and document it.  If it happens that there are use cases for other encodings, make that an option through the command line or other means.